# XMLHTTP status code 0 when connecting to salesforce

Tags: javascript, rest, salesforce, apex, cross-site

### Disclaimer:

I've seen several posts regarding status codes 0 here, but a lot of them give answers of the form "it's API specific" etc... and don't seem to serve my purpose. So i'm going to ask again a specific question here to platform i'm working on Salesforce, this is a very popular tool, so I don't believe the scope of this will be too narrow, for those that wish to close the question.

### Question Begins:

I'm working on making an APEX page that should query a REST resource built in Salesforce.

The REST resource works just fine when tested with POSTMAN, as well as my own python client, but somehow I cannot access it via javascript from the website. The code is given below:

```
<apex:page>
<html>
    <head>

        <script>


            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


            xhr.open("GET", "http://URLredacted.salesforce.com/apexrest/resourcenameredacted", false);
            xhr.send();
            alert(xhr.state);
            alert(xhr.status);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

When i set the async parameter to true, the values I get back are xhr.status = 0, and xhr.state = undefined. When it is false, the alerts just never happen in the first place.

Once again the resource being consumed is a working and tested REST API.

Is there a fix for this, in salesforce specifically?

Comment: a) If you set `async` to true, you need to use a callback to retrieve the result. b) do you get any error messages in the web developer console? what does the network tab there show?

Comment: I would suggest you set Debug Logs on Salesforce side and see why it's happening. Also, as already mentioned by @Thilo, check web developer console for any errors.